# Rudin PMA's explanation errata in page 155?

Tags: real-analysis

At page 155 of Rudin's PMA book Chapter 7, it reads 
" However, even if {f_n} is a uniformly bounded sequence of continuous
functions on a compact set E, there need not exist a subsequence which converges
pointwise on E."

I think the word 'pointwise' in the sentence above seems to be an errata which should be replaced by 'uniformly'. 
Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not. By Tychonov's theorem the sequence is indeed relatively compact with respect to the topology of pointwise convergence -- but this topology is not metrizable and hence you cannot conclude sequential compactness.

Comment: There is no error. In fact, the very next paragraph provides an example of this claim, with $f_n(x) = \sin(nx)$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: *Errata* does not mean *error*.